# Find RHS from LHS.

Tags: analysis, mathematical-modeling, computational-mathematics

$A=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]<==>\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]=A^{'}$
$B=\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]<===>\left[
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]=B^{'}$

From the above we can obtain the RHS matrices from LHS  by replacing $k\times k$
block submatrices in the corresponding entries of A. Here, in the above example $k=2$. Here My question is how to denote RHS matrix in terms of LHS in general?

Comment: Looks like a tensor product $A\otimes\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ with suitable choice of basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_k$ denote the $k\times k$-matrix with entries only $1$, hence 
$$ E_k = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
                         \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then, with $\otimes$ denoting the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), we have
$$ A' = A \otimes E_2, B' = B \otimes E_2 $$